# Modify actual code file(c#, java, etc) of a previous commit (using git)?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

Is it possible to modify code(C#, java, etc..) from a previous commit (some days back) and make code changes to it. Commit it again. I usually commit code using Visual studio team explorer. But using git is it possible (using Amend, rebase commands)? Also, does the commit # change?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use [`git checkout --detach <commit>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

> git checkout [--detach] | commit |
>
> Prepare to work on top of , by detaching HEAD at it (see "DETACHED HEAD" section), and updating the index and the files in the working tree. Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept, so that the resulting working tree will be the state recorded in the commit plus the local modifications.
>
> When the  argument is a branch name, the --detach option can be used to detach HEAD at the tip of the branch (git checkout  would check out that branch without detaching HEAD).
>
> Omitting  detaches HEAD at the tip of the current branch.

I suggest doing this in a new branch and testing your changes there before merging or rebasing to master.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your question is the real key:

> ... Also, does the commit # change?

The answer is *yes*.  A commit hash ID is specific to that one commit.  *All* commits are frozen for all time.  You cannot change them!  What you can do is make a new and improved *replacement* commit.  That, for instance, is what `git commit --amend` does.  It's also what `git rebase` does, except that `rebase` does it automatically for *many* commits.

Hence, to do this in command-line Git, you first `git checkout` the specific commit you don't like:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- branch-X
           ^
           |
     mistake here
```

You can:

```
git checkout <hash-of-H>
```

to get it into your index and work-tree as a *detached HEAD*.  (This also gives you a chance to inspect the commit, to see if it really is where you want to start the reworking.)  Then you can create a new branch name and switch to that new branch:

```
git checkout -b rework
```

Or, if you like, you can combine these into a single command:

```
git checkout -b rework <hash-of-H>
```

The result is:

```
             I--J   <-- branch-X
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- rework (HEAD)
```

I've attached the name `HEAD` to branch name `rework`, to show which branch you're on.  (You're no longer in the "detached HEAD" mode, if you used the two step process to first verify which commit you want to rework.)

You can now make some changes in your work-tree, `git add`, and run `git commit --amend`.  The `--amend` option tells your Git to shove the current commit out of the way, making a new commit whose parent is the parent of the current commit.  Let's call the new commit `K`, and draw it like this:

```
          H--I--J   <-- branch-X
         /
...--F--G--K   <-- rework (HEAD)
```

As you can see, commit `H` is still present, and still on branch `branch`.  Branch name `rework`, however, now identifies new commit `K`, and new commit `K`'s parent is commit `G`, instead of the usual case: the `--amend` made Git use `G` as the parent, instead of using `H` as the parent.

You can now re-copy commits `I` and `J` to new and improved `I'` and `J'` commits.  Using `git rebase`, you can do this in an automated fashion—but it may be more instructive, at least once, to do this with `git cherry-pick`, because that's essentially how `git rebase` really works.

So, from here, to cherry-pick `I` and `J`:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-I>
```

This will tell Git to compare `I` vs `H`, to see what `I` does, then try to make the *same* changes to your commit `K` and automatically make a new commit that re-uses the commit message from `I` too:

```
          H--I--J   <-- branch-X
         /
...--F--G--K--I'  <-- rework (HEAD)
```

If all goes well, you can now `git cherry-pick` commit `J` (by its hash ID, or by using the name `branch-X`, which identifies commit `J`, as you can see in the drawing).  If that goes well you now have:

```
          H--I--J   <-- branch-X
         /
...--F--G--K--I'-J'  <-- rework (HEAD)
```

Now all you have to do is force your Git to move the *name* `branch` to identify commit `J'`:

```
git branch -f branch-X rework
```

which results in:

```
          H--I--J   [abandoned]
         /
...--F--G--K--I'-J'  <-- branch-X, rework (HEAD)
```

You can now go back to `branch-X`: `git checkout branch-X` will attaching `HEAD` to the name `branch-X`, without changing anything else.  Then you can delete the name `rework` since we no longer need it.

Note that *all three commits* are now "renumbered".  Really, they're just three *new* commits: the three original commits are still there, frozen for all time.  They're just *invisible* now, or at least, not find-able through the name `branch-X` any more.  Eventually, the three commits will go away entirely, as long as there's no way to find them.

(Git tries to give you at least 30 days to change your mind and get them back.  To do that, you have to find the hash ID of commit `J` ... which isn't all that hard, really, using `git reflog`.  After the 30 day time period, though, Git *expires* the reflog entry that remembers `J`'s hash ID, and that's when the commit will really, truly go away, as long as there's no *other* way to find it.)

#### Automating this

You can automate this entire process using `git rebase`, especially `git rebase -i`.  I'd encourage you to do it first by hand, the hard way, a few times, to get a good feel for how it works and what goes wrong.  But to do this with `git rebase -i`, you would run:

```
git rebase -i <hash-of-G>
```

The reason for using the hash of commit `G`, instead of that of `H`, is that what `git rebase` really does is:

- Make a list of the commits that it should copy, as if by `git cherry-pick`: these are the commits that are on the current branch, but *after* the commit you listed.  So that's `H`, `I`, and `J`.
- Then, check out the specific commit you asked for (`G` in this case) and, in effect, run `git cherry-pick` on each of the commits listed in the first step.

When you use `git rebase -i`, Git pauses—by running your editor—between the two steps, having written out an instruction sheet of `pick` commands.  These `pick` commands represent each cherry-pick operation to be done.<sup>1</sup>  You can edit this instruction sheet now, changing `pick` commands to other commands, swapping around `pick` commands, or whatever you like.  (There are instructions on the instruction sheet, in the form of comments, to tell you how to edit it.)  You make whatever changes—such as changing `pick` to `edit`—and write out the updated sheet and exit your editor, and Git begins following the instructions.

If you use the `edit` instruction, Git runs the cherry-pick, then stops after the cherry-pick has finished successfully.  You can then use `git commit --amend` on to push the current (cherry-picked copy) commit out of the way.

The tricky part here is that, regardless of what you do with the instructions, it's possible for some of the cherry-pick operations to *fail*.  If and when they *do* fail, they don't get *rejected*.  Instead, they stop in the middle.  You are left in the middle of a conflicted `git merge` operation, as cherry-pick is just a weird form of merge, to Git.  **You must know how to resolve a conflicted merge.**  This means you should learn how to work `git merge` *before* you learn how to work `git cherry-pick`, and you should learn how to work `git cherry-pick` before you run `git rebase`.

Finishing the interrupted rebase-driven cherry-pick is (usually) pretty easy: you resolve the conflict, `git add` the correct files, and run `git rebase --continue`.  Note that you can get a conflict on a commit you intended to `edit`: in this case, the stop happens *before* the new commit is committed.  You have to finish the conflicted merge and run `git rebase --continue` to get the commit made.  (I forget whether Git then (1) makes the commit and (2) stops to let you amend it, but I suspect it does.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The *as if by cherry-pick* also usually becomes *actually by cherry-pick* here.  All forms of `git rebase` will try to do a little cheating to make things go faster and/or smoother and/or better, but interactive rebase does the least cheating, since you get to stop at every step and look.